# Rationale for two-components in feedback loop of circadian molecular clock

Tags: molecular-biology, circadian-rhythms

The circadian clock in humans and fruit flies involves a feedback loop in which the active components are protein heterodimers. This is illustrated for humans in the diagram below:

[image: Circadian feedback loop]

The nuclear proteins MBAL1 and CLOCK form a dimer which is a specific transcription factor for the genes of proteins PER and CRYS. The mRNAs for the later are transported to the cytoplasm for translation, where a PER/CRYS heterodimer is formed. This is transported to the nucleus (generally in a chemically modified form) where it inhibits the MBAL1/CLOCK dimer, and hence the transcription of the PER and CRYS genes.

The diagram above is take from [Ko and Takashi (2006)](https://academic.oup.com/hmg/article/15/suppl_2/R271/624758) and a summary of the process can be found in the Wikipedia entry for [Circadian Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_clock).

I wish to know if there is any known reason or rationale for this feedback loop involving proteins that are made of two separate components, and whether simpler systems involving a single-component transcription feedback loop exist, for example in more primitive organisms.

Comment: Heterodimer of what? You need to provide more information about the process (preferably supported by a reference source) for your question to be intelligible.

Comment: In mice models, I speak of the heterodimerization of BMAL1-CLOCK and in fruit flies this is CLOCK-CYC. These are mentioned in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_clock (scroll down to Mammalian Clocks and Insect Clocks section)

Comment: One question that is implicit here is whether complex biological feedback loops exist that _do not_ have heterodimers. Heterodimerization is a fundamental design component of biological systems in cells. I don't have a reference but I'd be very surprised to find any complex cellular system that didn't involve the heterodimerization of protein components as a step!

Comment: As an example, [the arabidopsis circadian clock involves a variety of distinct protein complexes](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/068460v1.full.pdf) (which at times are heterodimers), some of them homologous to animal models.

Comment: I think your question is valid, but the lack of response suggests that the problem could be presented more clearly. I have taken the liberty to do so. You can roll it back if you like or edit it further.